# excel match index if exists

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup

I have 2 excel sheets:

Sheet1:  (Value = Prevalue)

```
Id   Preval Value    
111  1      1
123  2      2
100  3      3
```

Sheet2:

```
Id Num Date
111 5
123 6  1/1/18
100 7
```

I want to perform a logic saying that:  Matching the 2 sheets by Id, if Date on sheet2 exists then Value on sheet1 = num on sheet2 else = Prevalue

```
Id Value
111  1    (same)
123  6    (update since date exists)
100  3    (same)
```

How would this be done using index or vlookup?  Many thanks!

Comment: The problem is the keeping of the existing,  You can have a formula or you can have a set value, not both.  If you put in a formula that is live and it will return the value from Sheet2, whether that be a blank cell or a date.  If you enter a value it will overwrite the formula.  To do what you are asking will require vba.

Comment: the existing values were derived from another cell so I can implement that in the formula.  I was thinking it could be IF(exist,update,"old formula")

Comment: @ScottCranerI made the change.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$C$4,3,0)="",B2,VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$C$4,2,0))
```

[image]